# How to update different columns on different views on Rails 4 for the same Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 models.

```
Scoreboard Model : can have many teams 
Team Model : belongs to Scoreboard

Teams has the follow columns: 
name: string
win,loss,tie: integer
```

On the Team#Index view, I have a collection of all the teams associated to the Scoreboard. Also on that page, I can render an edit form on top of each team object and update it through ajax. Here is the relevant code:

**Team#Index View:**

```
<div class="team-list">
    <%= render @teams.reject(&:new_record?) %>
</div>
```

**_team.html.erb**

```
  <div class="row team-div" id="team_<%=team.id%>">

   <%= link_to (scoreboard_team_path(@scoreboard, team)) do %>
      <div class="col-xs-4 team-div-1"> <%= team.name %> </div>
   <% end %>

   <%= link_to (edit_scoreboard_team_path(@scoreboard, team)), remote: true, class: "team-edit-link" do %>
           <div class="col-xs-6 team-data">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 team-div-2"><%= team.win %> </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 team-div-2"><%= team.loss %> </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 team-div-2"><%= team.tie %></div>
            </div>
           </div>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

As you can see, I have an edit link available which renders an edit form in place of the `team object` in question through ajax. The edit form only updates the `win,loss,tie` columns.

**Edit form rendered:**

```
<%= form_for [@scoreboard, @team], remote: true do |f| %> 

     <div class="row team-edit-form">
        <div class="col-xs-4 edit-team-1">Placeholder</div>


        <div class="col-xs-2 edit-team-2"><%= f.number_field :win, min: 0, max: 9999, class: "form-control", placeholder: "0"  %></div>


        <div class="col-xs-2 edit-team-2"><%= f.number_field :loss, min: 0, max: 9999, class: "form-control", placeholder: "0" %></div>

        <div class="col-xs-2 edit-team-2"><%= f.number_field :tie, min: 0, max: 9999, class: "form-control", placeholder: "0" %></div>

        <div class="col-xs-2 edit-team-3"> <%= f.submit "Done", :data => {:disable_with => "Saving..."}, class: "btn btn-primary" %></div>
     </div>
 <% end %>
```

Team#update Controller Method(which by ajax reloads the newly edited team object div):

```
def update
    @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])
    @team = @scoreboard.teams.find(params[:id])
    if @team.update_attributes(team_params)
     respond_to do |format|
         format.html {redirect_to scoreboard_teams_path(@scoreboard)}
         format.js
     end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
         format.html {redirect_to scoreboard_teams_path(@scoreboard)}
         format.js { render action: "update_error" }
     end
    end
 end
```

Now for my problem. All the above happens on the team#index view by ajax. 
On the team#show view, I would like to edit only the team name without ajax.

So far, this is what the team#show view looks like:

**Team#show View**

```
<h3> <%= @team.name %> <h3>

<%= form_for [@scoreboard, @team] do |f| %>

        <div class="col-xs-4"><%= f.text_field :name, required: true, maxlength: 30, class: "team-name-field form-control", placeholder: "Enter name"  %></div>

        <div class="col-xs-1"> <%= f.submit "Update", :data => {:disable_with => "Saving..."}, class: "btn btn-primary" %></div>

<% end %>
```

Upon submission, I would like to update the name and then redirect the page back to the team#show(no ajax required). Currently, this form also routes to the same update method. Is it possible to use the same update method but execute different response code for the team#show view? If not, how can I have a customized update code executed when I submit the form on the team#show page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can use a different respond_to as you can only redirect or render once in an action.

One approach would be to create a new route / controller method for updating the team name.

routes

```
resources :teams do
  member { post 'update_name' }
end
```

show.html.erb

In the view, you can post to the above route and in the controller, create a method for the new route.

```
<%= form_for @team, :url => update_name_team_path(@team)
```

teams_controller

```
def update_name
  @team = Team.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to team_path(@team)
end
```

Comment: My normal update method is really cluttered so I was looking for something like this. Except `post` does not work for me. My intent is to edit a already created element so `patch` works for me. Is that alright?

Comment: Perfect, indeed I should have spotted that as you are updating the model. `put` would also work.

Comment: If I may ask another question, what is the difference between put and patch?

Comment: `put` is the older form of `patch` and whilst `patch` is the preferred verb by rails for updates, its good to know about both. [This](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/2/26/edge-rails-patch-is-the-new-primary-http-method-for-updates/) is a good explanation. I

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this by checking the request type or sending a flag/keyword to check for the response to render, I would do it like :

Add `hidden_field` for request param in edit form like :

```
<%= form_for [@scoreboard, @team], remote: true do |f| %> 

     <div class="row team-edit-form">
        <div class="col-xs-4 edit-team-1">Placeholder</div>


        <div class="col-xs-2 edit-team-2"><%= f.number_field :win, min: 0, max: 9999, class: "form-control", placeholder: "0"  %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :request, 'js' %> </div>


        <div class="col-xs-2 edit-team-2"><%= f.number_field :loss, min: 0, max: 9999, class: "form-control", placeholder: "0" %></div>

        <div class="col-xs-2 edit-team-2"><%= f.number_field :tie, min: 0, max: 9999, class: "form-control", placeholder: "0" %></div>

        <div class="col-xs-2 edit-team-3"> <%= f.submit "Done", :data => {:disable_with => "Saving..."}, class: "btn btn-primary" %></div>
     </div>
 <% end %>
```

Add `hidden_field` for request param in name edit form in show page like :

```
<%= form_for [@scoreboard, @team] do |f| %>

        <div class="col-xs-4"><%= f.text_field :name, required: true, maxlength: 30, class: "team-name-field form-control", placeholder: "Enter name"  %> 
         <%= f.hidden_field :request, 'http' %> </div>

        <div class="col-xs-1"> <%= f.submit "Update", :data => {:disable_with => "Saving..."}, class: "btn btn-primary" %></div>

<% end %>
```

`Team#Update` Method will be like :

```
def update
    @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])
    @team = @scoreboard.teams.find(params[:id])
    if @team.update_attributes(team_params)
         redirect_to scoreboard_teams_path(@scoreboard)  if params[:request] == 'http'
         render ""  if params[:request] == 'js'
    else
         redirect_to scoreboard_teams_path(@scoreboard) if params[:request] == 'http'
         render action: "update_error"  if params[:request] == 'js'
    end
 end
```